# Does slight size discrepancy in retina 2x image matter?

Tags: jquery, css, retina.js

I am adapting my webpage for retina displays and i am using IrfanView to double my image.However,an image that was ordinarily `640 x 427 px` now becomes `1281 x 855 px`.Will this work with as expected?.I am using retina js too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want add images for retina display you must do this:

for normal screens:

```
background: url('example_image.png') no-repeat; (example_image.png 640px x 427px)
```

for retina display:

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx){
  .your_element{
    background: url('example_image@2x.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 640px 427px; 
  }
}
```

(example_image@2x.png 1280px x 854px)

Comment: That's very cool.One question though,earlier i managed to double the images but on opera i did `-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 4/2`. Is this acceptable?.

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't use this ratio, maybe this is correct because 2/1 is this same 2/4 but I'm not sure. I use this style 2/1 and working great but you can try.